# Spring-security: Replacement for deprecated .shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(false)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, deprecated

In my application, I have a security config which includes:

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // some code
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(customiser -> customiser
                    .shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(false)
                    .requestMatchers("/**")
                    .authenticated());
    // some code
    return http.build()
```

I need to specifically allow dispatcherTypes as I have a controller which returns `ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody>`. I assume that this means that DispatcherType.ASYNC needs to be allowed.

However, `.shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(false)` is deprecated for removal in spring-boot 3.2.2. The documentation suggests using `.dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType... type)` instead. However, when I attempt to introduce that method into my code, I am not able to specify `.requestMatchers()` in the method chain. I.e. this doesn't work:

```java
            http.authorizeHttpRequests(customiser -> customiser
                    .dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.values())
                    .requestMatchers("/**") // <-- the return value of dispatcherTypeMatchers doesn't have this method.
                    .authenticated());
```

How can I replace the code in the first block with something which isn't deprecated for removal?

Comment: `/**` already matches everything and so does the `dispatcherTypeMatchers` so you don't need it. Also a request matcher would just work, so not sure why you would need/want the dispatcher type as normally it will ignore that completly.

Comment: When using the code in the first block, I get a positive response. However, when I change it to `http.authorizeHttpRequests(customiser -> customiser.dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.values()).authenticated());` My controller throws an exception with `Cannot dispatch without an AsyncContext`. Is my config incorrect?

Comment: You changed `shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(false)` basically to `true` with your current configuration. When setting it to `false` you disable filtering for `ERROR`, `FORWARD` and `ASYNC` and thus those won't be matched. With your new configuration you have fitlering enabled for those. So to match the original `false` you should only filter `REQUEST` and `INCLUDE` not the others.

Comment: I see. That would mean that the positive responses I get is due to some other request matching. This helps a lot! Thank you!